# IBKR TWS API - reqRealTimeBars under delayed streaming for equities

Tags: python, interactive-brokers, stockquotes, tws

The IBKR delayed mode allows one to collect streaming market data without paying the market data subscriptions. I am wondering if it can also be used to fetch delayed 5-second bars while bypassing the Market Data Lines limit.

Specifically, when switching the TWS API to delayed streaming data by invoking reqMarketDataType with a parameter of 3:

a. Does reqRealTimeBars work in delayed data mode? Is the output identical except for the delay in receiving it?

b. Is it subject to the Market Data Lines limit (set to 100 by default) in delayed mode or can it be used to receive delayed 5-second bars for an unlimited number of stocks?

Thank you